# Como escrever HTML dentro do success do Ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc

Estou com um projeto em `ASP.NET MVC 4` e nele tenho uma requisição `Ajax` onde chama a `controller` mandando apenas um parâmetro. A requisição faz tudo corretamente, me trás uma lista com os dados que eu preciso.

O que eu quero saber é como eu posso usar essa lista pra escrever um código em `Html` dentro da success.

Ou se eu posso pegar a resposta do `Ajax` e usar a lista no `Html` fora do success.

Código AJAX:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
              var item = "";
              $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST', 
                  url: "@Url.Action("_ListaHistorico", "Solicitacoes")", 
                  data: { IdSolicitacao: id}, 
                  dataType: 'JSON', 
                  success: function (result) {
                      for (var i = 0; i <= result.lenght; i++) {
                      }
                  },
                  error: function (msg) {
                      alert("ERRO!");
                  }
              });
          </script>
```

Código Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult _ListaHistorico(int IdSolicitacao)
{
    List<List<string>> listaHistorico = new List<List<string>>();
    foreach (
        var historico in
            context.Solicitacao.Include("Usuario")
                .Where(x => x.IdSolicitacao == IdSolicitacao)
                .FirstOrDefault()
                .HistoricoSolicitacao.ToList())
    {
        listaHistorico.Add(new List<string>
        {
            historico.DataCadastro.Value.ToShortDateString(),
            historico.Usuario.Nome,
            historico.Observacao
        });
    }

    return Json(listaHistorico, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Só pra te avisar, você errou na digitação em `result.lenght` o correto seria `result.lenght`, eu já editei. Se você colocou no código desta forma, este seria um problema ^^

Comment: @PauloRoberto Não sei se essa edição foi boa ideia, parece-me pouco provável que o autor tenha estado a escrever letra a letra, linha a linha o código para o colocar na pergunta... É mais provável que foi copy&paste e que o _typo_ está a ser o problema / um problema que ele está a ter.

Comment: @Zuul você tem razão, voltei atrás.

Comment: Realmente estava errado a sintaxe. Obrigado por corrigirem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você vai ter que construir o HTML dentro do método `success` usando strings, ou então alguma biblioteca de templates, e então fazer um `append` em algum elemento HTML que já esteja na página.

Além disso o seu controller poderia ser melhorado de forma a facilitar o trabalho no javascript.

Exemplo:

Em seu controller, poderia retornar objetos anônimos de forma a facilitar no retorno de propriedades:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult _ListaHistorico(int IdSolicitacao)
{
    var listaHistorico = context.Solicitacao.Include("Usuario")
        .Where(x => x.IdSolicitacao == IdSolicitacao)
        .FirstOrDefault()
        .HistoricoSolicitacao
        .Select(x => new
        {
            DataCadastro = x.DataCadastro.Value.ToShortDateString(),
            UsuarioNome = x.Usuario.Nome,
            x.Observacao,
        })
        .ToList();

    return Json(listaHistorico, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Neste caso, quando o objeto chegasse no `result` da função atribuida ao `success` você teria um json com a seguinte estrutura de exemplo:

```
[
    { "DataCadastro": "2014-03-10", "UsuarioNome": "Miguel", "Observacao": "xpto 1" },
    { "DataCadastro": "2014-03-15", "UsuarioNome": "Angelo", "Observacao": "xpto 2" },
]
```

Com essa estrutura de json, você pode iterar usando um `for`, e para cada elemento, ler as propriedades `DataCadastro`, `UsuarioNome` e `Observacao`. Dessa forma, você pode então construir a string contendo o HTML, e finalmente usar o `append`.

```
  success: function (result) {
      for (var i = 0; i <= result.length; i++) {
          var item = result[i];
          $("#idDoContainer").append(
              "<div>" +
              "  <div>DataCadastro: " + item.DataCadastro + "</div>" +
              "  <div>DataCadastro: " + item.UsuarioNome + "</div>" +
              "  <div>DataCadastro: " + item.Observacao + "</div>" +
              "</div>"
              );
      }
  },
```

Comment: Ele tem `dataType: 'JSON'`, o que me leva a crer que a dificuldade está em trabalhar os dados recebidos... :/

Comment: correto seria `result.length`

Comment: Corrigido. Value!

Comment: Fazer referência ao facto de que ele tem um _typo_ no código! A origem do problema poderá estar nesse _typo_...

Comment: já fiz @Zuul mas é sempre bom alertar

Comment: @PauloRoberto Eu vi, mas aqui na resposta do Miguel estava mesmo a falar para ele adicionar essa info na resposta. E tu faz o mesmo ;)

Comment: É pelo fato de eu ter copiado o código da pergunta, que também está errado.

Comment: Funcionou pra mim @MiguelAngelo, obrigado!

Comment: Disponha meu amigo! Estou à disposição.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar uma HTML String e jogar ela em seu documento, desta maneira:

```
          var item = "";
          $.ajax({
              type: 'POST', 
              url: "@Url.Action("_ListaHistorico", "Solicitacoes")", 
              data: { IdSolicitacao: id}, 
              dataType: 'JSON', 
              success: function (result) {
                  var strHTML = "";
                  for (var i = 0; i <= result.length; i++) {
                    strHTML = strHTML + "<li> "+result[i]+"</li>";
                  }
                  strHTML = "<ul>" + strHTML + "</ul>";
                  document.body.innerHTML(strHTML); //transforma o conteudo do body em sua lista
              },
              error: function (msg) {
                  alert("ERRO!");
              }
          });
```

## Muito importante:

Você errou na digitação de `result.lenght` o correto seria `result.length` como eu usei acima, se você usou `result.lenght` em seu código, com certeza houve um erro por causa disto.